# File.renameTo() in the same directory slow on some devices

Tags: java, android, file

I have observed that on some Android devices (e.g. the Sony Xperia Z5), `file.renameTo(newFilePath)` is really slow for video files, even when the new path is in the same folder (which should not trigger a rewrite at all). It takes several seconds for the rename to happen.

This happens e.g for files in the application's data folder:

```
File file = new File("/storage/0123-4567/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/recordings/a.mp4")
File newFile = new File("/storage/0123-4567/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/recordings/a_appendix.mp4");
file.renameTo(newFile);
```

Is there any known issue for renameTo or a better way to just append something to an existing file's name? It only happens on a fraction of devices I have tested this with so far - but on those it does, it happens every time.

Comment: how do you measure "slow" ? does the same "slow" happen if you rename a much smaller jpg file? if you define "slow==cpu gets busy" remember that the media-scanner mus reread the renamed file to update it-s media-db. the usb-file-server must be updated, too

Comment: Slow means, that this call blocks for 3-4 seconds for a small video (6 MB) .The files are in a folder ``files/recordings/`` and I put a nomedia here: ``files/.nomedia``, so the meda-db should ignore that, shouldn't it? Renaming a jpeg takes 40ms (still a long time considering only the file handle should be changed)